# Resize animated GIF file without destroying animation

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, animated-gif

I need to resize an animated GIF file without destroying the animation.

How can I do it using PHP?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

if you have imagemagick access, you can do this:

```
system("convert big.gif -coalesce coalesce.gif");
system("convert -size 200x100 coalesce.gif -resize 200x10 small.gif");
```

this is most likely possible with the imagemagick plugin if you don't have system() access

NOTE: this may create a larger filesize though a smaller dimensions image due to coalescing essentially deoptimizing the image.

**UPDATE:**
If you don't have ImageMagick access, you should be able to use a combination of the following steps to resize an animated gif (assuming you have GD access):

1. Detect if the image is an animated gif: [Can I detect animated gifs using php and gd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280658/can-i-detect-animated-gifs-using-php-and-gd) (top answer)
2. Split the animated gif into individual frames: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3234-PHP-Split-GIF-animations-into-multiple-images.html
3. Resize the individual frames: http://www.akemapa.com/2008/07/10/php-gd-resize-transparent-image-png-gif/
4. Recomposite the frames into an animated gif again: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html

This is definitely much more intensive than the ImageMagick route, but it should be technically possible.

If you get it working, please share with the world!

Comment: sorry, I don't have access on imagemagic. Any other solution?

Comment: Posted an update with a number of steps using GD and third party classes to make this happen (in theory).

Comment: I think I got the theory just about working in practice: http://forssto.com/gifexample/

Comment: @JeremyStanley's approach is very correct. You can see a full tutorial [here](http://phpimageworkshop.com/tutorial/5/manage-animated-gif-with-imageworkshop.html)

Answer (score 12):

Try <s>GDEnhancer</s> (Use [ImageCraft](https://github.com/coldume/imagecraft)). It only need GD Library, and it keep gif animation

Comment: Thanks. Can it be used with PHP 5.2? On the site it says 5.4+, which is pretty cutting edge for most environments (including my target environment in this case).
Otherwise looks great!

Comment: Alas, GDEnhancer website is dead.

Comment: @TechNyquist now GDEnhacer is deprecated, use https://github.com/coldume/imagecraft instead

Comment: downloaded from source, it didn't work well. some weirdness with namespaces

Answer (score 11):

You would need to decompose the gif into frames, thumbnail and re-assemble.

Have a look at [ImageMagick](https://secure.php.net/imagick) and [this tutorial](https://phpro.org/examples/Thumbnail-From-Animated-GIF.html).

Answer (score 6):

I have tried numerous examples of resizing animated GIFs with Imagick PHP module, but none of them worked for me.
Then after some debugging time at last I found the actual issue: the animation was lost upon saving image to disk, by `$animation->writeImage($file_dst);` or 
`$animation->writeImages($file_dst, true);`

I've changed it to 
`file_put_contents($file_dst, $animation->getImagesBlob());`
and most examples started working immediately.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Amazing!! This saved my day! Thanks Anthony. Old versions of Imagick are buggy when using writeImages but using your method works fine and no problems at all! :)

Comment: this did the trick when writeImages() would strip the animation.

Answer (score 4):

The example on http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php will resize your gif while retaining your frame timing. Something most of the other examples do not do.

Other examples *rebuild* the gif while this one allows you to *modify* the frames of the image.

Comment: imagick is the best at complex image manipulation. PHP does know a few tricks to.

Comment: That's the solution I went for finally, I tried other solutions, but they were prohibitively slow.
Make sure you have Imagick on your hosting (it's not such a rare thing nowadays) and use that.

Answer (score 4):

If you have ImageMagick installed then you can use a single call to `convert`:

```
system("convert big.gif -coalesce -repage 0x0 -resize 200x100 -layers Optimize small.gif");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got this in the bag.

This solution is by no means perfect and contains some brute force here and there, but I was able to append my GD / PHP based image resizing script with enough functionality to support animations.

The solution is heavily based on the excellent freeware libraries by László Zsidi - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/author/283569.html

You can check out a quick demo and download the sources from http://forssto.com/gifexample/ (direct link: http://forssto.com/gifexample/gifanimresize.zip )

KNOWN ISSUES:

- Transparency support - this would be
  easy to append to this solution, but
  as I don't have an immediate need for
  this, I'm stopping here.
- Frame rate - for some unknown reason
  the GifEncoder class fails to take
  into account the frame rates
  specified. I'll need to look into
  this later.
- I did find one gif file from my set
  of tests that somehow had different
  sized frames in it and that animation
  failed to work correctly. Still some
  debugging to do then.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I tried your solution. I modified the sources to read the image from a string (let me know if you're interested) but it turned out to be WAAAY to slow. I finally realized that Imagick was available on the hosting and used that instead.

Answer (score 1):

just creat 3 folder name 1.frame_output 2.images 3.resized_frame_output and download 2 encoder and decoder class from this below link 
1.Download class "GIFDecoder.class.php" from http://phpclasses.elib.com/browse/package/3234.html 
2.Download class "GIFEncoder.class.php" from http://phpclasses.betablue.net/browse/package/3163.html

and then run the script name as "resize_animator.php" , creat a upload html file & Let Enjoy the script.

..save this script as .....index.php.......

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="resize_animator.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td align="center"><font face="Tahoma">SELECT ANIMATED FILE</font> 
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" size="20" accept="image/gif"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="PROCESS ANIMATION" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

........................save and this script as resize_animator.php............

```
   <?php

   require "GIFDecoder.class.php";
   include "GIFEncoder.class.php";
   $file_name= $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
   $file_ext = substr($file_name, -4);
   $file_size=($_FILES["uploadfile"]["size"] /1024 );
   if($file_ext=='.gif')
    {
 if($file_size > 0 && $file_size < 2000 )
  {
    session_start ( );
        $uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fp=file_get_contents($uploaded_file);

        if ( $fp )
            {
                $_SESSION['delays'] = Array ( );
                $gif = new GIFDecoder ( $fp );
                $arr = $gif->GIFGetFrames ( );
                $_SESSION [ 'delays' ] = $gif -> GIFGetDelays ( );

                for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $arr ); $i++ )
                {
                        fwrite ( fopen ( ( $i < 10 ? "frame_output/$i$i_frame.gif" : "frame_output/$i_frame.gif" ), "wb" ), $arr [ $i ] );
                }
          }

        function resize_frames($newwidth,$newheight)
            {
                    $dir=opendir("frame_output/");
                    $i=0;
                    while($imgfile=readdir($dir))
                    {
                         if ($imgfile != "." && $imgfile!="..")
                             {
                                        $imgarray[$i]=$imgfile;
                                        $uploadedfile = "frame_output/".$imgarray[$i];
                                        $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
                                        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
                                        $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
                                        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
                                        $filename = "resized_frame_output/".$imgarray[$i];
                                        imagegif($tmp,$filename,100);
                                        imagedestroy($src);
                                        imagedestroy($tmp);
                                        $i++;
                            }
                    }
                    closedir($dir);

                if ( $dh = opendir ( "resized_frame_output/" ) )
                {
                    while ( false !== ( $dat = readdir ( $dh ) ) )
                    {
                        if ( $dat != "." && $dat != ".." )
                        {
                            $frames [ ] = "resized_frame_output/$dat";
                        }
                    }
                    closedir ( $dh );
                }

            $gif = new GIFEncoder   ( $frames,$_SESSION [ 'delays' ],0, 2, 0, 0, 0,"url" );
            $data = $gif->GetAnimation ( );

            $x='x';
            $y='_';
            $uploaded_file_name= $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
            $actual_file_name = substr($uploaded_file_name, 0, -4);
            $file_extention = substr($uploaded_file_name, -4);
            $new_name=$actual_file_name.$y.$newwidth.$x.$newheight.$file_extention ;

            //$output_image_name=$newwidth.$x.$newheight;
            fwrite ( fopen ( "images/$new_name", "wb" ), $data );
            //remove resized frames from folder
            //sleep for 1 second
            // usleep(2000000);
            $dir = 'resized_frame_output/';
            foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v)
                {
                 unlink($v);
                }
        }  // end of function resize_frames


            $gif = new GIFEncoder   ( $frames,$_SESSION [ 'delays' ],0, 2, 0, 0, 0,"url" );
            $data = $gif->GetAnimation ( );

            $x='x';
            $y='_';
            $z='_p';
            $uploaded_file_name= $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
            $actual_file_name = substr($uploaded_file_name, 0, -4);
            $file_extention = substr($uploaded_file_name, -4);
            $new_name=$actual_file_name.$y.$newwidth.$x.$newheight.$z.$file_extention ;

            //$output_image_name=$newwidth.$x.$newheight;
            fwrite ( fopen ( "images/$new_name", "wb" ), $data );
            //remove resized frames from folder
            //sleep for 1 second
             //usleep(2000000);
            $dir = 'resized_frame_output/';
            foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v)
                {
                 unlink($v);
                }
        }  // end of function resize_frames

            resize_frames(110,110);
            resize_frames(120,160);
            resize_frames(120,80);
            resize_frames(128,96);
            resize_frames(128,128);
            resize_frames(208,208);
            resize_frames(208,320);

            session_destroy();

            //usleep(200000);

            //remove resized frames from folder
            $dir = 'frame_output/';
            foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v)
                {
                 unlink($v);
                }
      echo "<center><h1>Your Animation processing is compleated.</h1></center>";
      echo "<center><h2><a href=\"index.php\">BACK TO UPLOAD PAGE</h2></center>";
  }  //end of file size checker
else
 {
      echo "<center><h2>You Upload a unfit size image .Upload a file within 2000 KB</h2></center>";
      echo "<center><h2><a href=\"index.php\">BACK TO UPLOAD PAGE</h2></center>";
 }
   } //end of file extention checker
  else
  {
   echo "<center><h2>Uplaod a gif file!</h2></center>";
   echo "<center><h2><a href=\"index.php\">BACK TO UPLOAD PAGE</h2></center>";
  }
  ?>
```

.......................LETS ENJOY............

uncomment the usleep function to see the work happen into those folders.its not necessary but i use it to see the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This all answers except trough ImageMagick didnt work for me. Scripts in answers before this are all full of errors.

Even installing ImageMagick was difficult to manage so here is my experience.

Here is [how to install ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19439) on windows 7 and xampp 1.7.4.
*Note*: Choose 64 bit (for win7), and when installing leave checked the option "Add to system path".

And then follow:
http://www.creativearmory.com/tutorials/resize-animated-gifs-with-php-and-imagemagick

I have lost hours on scripts at this posts, and ImageMagick and this tutorial was sucessfull in minutes.

And one more note: my webserver have ImageMagick by default, so i guess most of servers have it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have Imagemagick in your server you may want to try this :

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7353-PHP-Resize-animations-in-files-of-the-GIF-format.html

The class is resizing GIF animations with GD. First parses the frames, then resizes them, after that it compiles them again into single file without losing its delay times,disposal methods, color tables etc.

Try and if you find a bug or want to suggest some optimizations etc. you can use the class' forum or leave a comment on the page in my website. And I'll answer that ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

[GIF Animation Resizer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7353-PHP-Resize-animations-in-files-of-the-GIF-format.html) is a simple one-class tool that will do the trick.

**Note:** It uses a temporary folder to write out the separate frames. While it timestamps the frames, you may need to create a unique folder if you intend to use this on a server where multiple users will be resizing GIFs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

[Imagecraft](https://github.com/coldume/imagecraft) is a reliable PHP GD library and extension that keeps GIF animation, edit and compose images in multiple layers and supports watermark.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function:

```
function gifResize($file_origin,$file_dest,$percent){       
   $crop_w = 0;
   $crop_h = 0;
   $crop_x = 0;
   $crop_y = 0;
   $image = new Imagick($file_origin);
   $originalWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
   $originalHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
   $size_w = ($originalWidth*$percent)/100;
   $size_h = ($originalHeight*$percent)/100;
   if(($size_w-$originalWidth)>($size_h-$originalHeight)){
       $s = $size_h/$originalHeight;
       $size_w = round($originalWidth*$s);
       $size_h = round($originalHeight*$s);
   }else{
       $s = $size_w/$originalWidth;
       $size_w = round($originalWidth*$s);
       $size_h = round($originalHeight*$s);
   }       
   $image = $image->coalesceImages();

   foreach ($image as $frame) {
       $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y);
       $frame->thumbnailImage($size_h, $size_w);
       $frame->setImagePage($size_h, $size_w, 0, 0);
   }
   $imageContent = $image->getImagesBlob();
   $fp = fopen($file_dest,'w');
   fwrite($fp,$imageContent);
   fclose($fp);
```

}