# Handling animated images with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image-manipulation

I already wrote a PHP script that allows users to upload images but I want to be able to allow my users to upload animated images. What do I need to add to my current code to allow animated images using PHP? A quick code example would help me out a lot.

Comment: have to see script and what animated image exactly you talking about..

Comment: Are you talking about animated .gifs?

Comment: @jatt my script is a little big to post.

Comment: @delimit Please post a link to it.

Comment: @NullUserException I have it on my localhost

Comment: @NullUserException yes I wrote it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to add to my current
>   code to allow animated images using
>   PHP?

Nothing. Animated images are images all the same.

---

**EDIT:** If you are resizing your images using GD, you'll lose the animation, since GD can't handle it correctly.
If you have the [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) plugin installed, you should use it instead of GD:

```
$thumb = new Imagick('myimage.gif');

$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');

$thumb->destroy();
```

See also: [Resize animated gif file without destroying animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation)

Comment: my script excepts gif, png and jpeg but animated images dont work at all they display as a single image with no animation.

Comment: @delimit The animation is probably lost due to (incorrect) manipulation (eg: resizing).

Answer (score 0):

If your script accepts gifs and pngs you should be all set.

Comment: my script excepts gif, png and jpeg but animated images dont work at all they display as a single image with no animation.

Comment: Is the image being processed in any way after the upload? (Think GD or imagemagick) --> NullUserException's answer is the way to go!