# Resizing animated images using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way I can resize animated images just using PHP without ruining the image and its animation?

Answer (score 1):

[Resize animated GIF file without destroying animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation)

Comment: how would I install imagemagick correctly so that I can use it with my php code?

Comment: @characters: that's another story(question)

Comment: so you are telling me I should ask another question?