# PHP crop animated gif

Tags: php, imagick

Is it possible somehow to crop animated gif with builtin php libraries, ie without using Imagick etc?

Thanks ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in"? None of PHP's image functions, (whether from GD or Imagemagick) are "built-in".

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "built-in" image processing libraries in PHP. You have to use GD, Imagick, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify my class' resize() method to get your animated gif cropped.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7353-PHP-Resize-animations-in-files-of-the-GIF-format.html

The class is resizing GIF animations with GD. First parses the frames, then resizes them, after that it compiles them again into single file without losing its delay times,disposal methods, color tables etc.

Comment: Hi tpaksu, it would be cool if your class had it built in. Also, I recommend you put your class on Github or Bitbucket or something. That phpclasses.org is crap and you have to register first.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem to crop GIF using Imagick

```
$image = new \Imagick('path_to_image');

foreach ($image as $frame) {
    $frame->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
    $frame->cropImage($width, $height, $x, $y);
    $frame->setImagePage($width, $height, 0, 0);
}

$blob = $image->getImageBlob();
```