# resize image with PythonMagick

Tags: python, image, resize, imagemagick

What i want is just to resize an image using PythonMagick 0.9.1.

Unfortunately there is no documentation yet.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728911/resize-animated-gif-with-pythonmagick) where user uses resize() with PythonMagick 0.9.3.
There is no resize() function in the 0.9.1 version and I don't want to upgrade for know.

Ιs there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740158/documents-and-examples-of-pythonmagick seems to answer this.

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong but I can't see where my question being answered there. I dont' want to use pythonmagickwand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the following is the suggested way:

```
i = PythonMagick.Image(img)
i.sample('!<width>x<height>')
```

Same thing without the exclamation mark would maintain aspect ratio as well.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `resize` method, you can use the `transform` method:

```
image = PythonMagick.Image(<filename>)
image.transform('<width>x<height>')
```