# Resizing animated GIF with GIFDecoder.class.php will cause transparency problems

Tags: php, resize, gif, animated-gif

I need to resize animated GIF in PHP without ImageMagick. I am using the latest GIFDecoder and GIFEncoder classes from PHPclasses. When I extract each frame from the GIF, I get blotches of transparent areas on all the frames but the first one, even though the GIF is not transparent at all. Even putting them back together does not work. I have tried other files but still have the same problem.

The original

[image: The original]

How it turned out

[image: How it turns out]

Individual frames

[image: Individual frames]

If there are other solutions to resizing animated GIF please tell me, too. Thanks!

Comment: How did you believe that animated GIFs worked?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't really know what you mean, but I added some exmaples so you can understand better.

Comment: try this. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7353-PHP-Resize-animations-in-files-of-the-GIF-format.html

Comment: Doesn't work. I get an error message.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I've since moved on to using Imagemagick.

Comment: www.gdenhancer.com  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It's way faster and more powerfull than any custom coded PHP class.

Please take a look at [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation). The top answer even offers an alternative solution, if you have no access to ImageMagick on your server.