# animated gif resize and upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image-processing

I have a problem with my image upload form. when i upload animated gif it dosent seems to animate anymore. is there any way to fix this problem? or if i can just skip resizing the .gif extension and only resize other file types like .jpg, png etc that will also be fine.

upload.php code

```
<?php

// replace with your mysql database details
$MySql_username     = "root"; //mysql username
$MySql_password     = ""; //mysql password
$MySql_hostname     = "localhost"; //hostname
$MySql_databasename = 'upload'; //databasename


$UploadDirectory    = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory, ends with slash & make sure folder exist
$UploadThumbDirectory ='uploads/thumb/';//Upload thumb Directory, ends with slash & make sure folder exist

//Some Settings
$ThumbMaxWidth          = 150; //Thumbnail width
$ThumbMaxHeight         = 150; //Thumbnail Height
$BigImageMaxWidth       = 700; //Resize Image width to
$BigImageMaxHeight      = 700; //Resize Image height to
$ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix

if (!@file_exists($UploadDirectory)) {
    //destination folder does not exist
    die("Make sure Upload directory exist!");
}

if (!@file_exists($UploadThumbDirectory)) {
    //destination folder does not exist
    die("Make sure Upload Thumb directory exist!");
}

if($_POST)
{   
    if(!isset($_POST['mName']) || strlen($_POST['mName'])<1)
    {
        //required variables are empty
        die("Title is empty!");
    }

    if(!isset($_FILES['mFile']))
    {
        //required variables are empty
        die("File is empty!");
    }


    if($_FILES['mFile']['error'])
    {
        //File upload error encountered
        die(upload_errors($_FILES['mFile']['error']));
    }

    $ImageName          = strtolower($_FILES['mFile']['name']); //uploaded file name
    $Imageitle          = $_POST['mName']; // file title
    $ImageExt           = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.')); //file extension
    $ImageType          = $_FILES['mFile']['type']; //file type
    $ImageSize          = $_FILES['mFile']["size"]; //file size
    $TempSrc            = $_FILES['mFile']['tmp_name'];
    $uploaded_date      = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $process        = true;

    //Validate file + create image from uploaded file.
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['mFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(($_FILES['mFile']['tmp_name'])));
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['mFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/bmp':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['mFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
    }
    //get Image Size
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

    //File Title will be used as new File name
    $NewName = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), strtolower($Imageitle));
    $DestRandImageName = $NewName.'_'.date("YmdHis").$ImageExt;
    $NewThumbFileName = $NewName.'_'.$ThumbPrefix.date("YmdHis").$ImageExt;




    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling our resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxWidth,$BigImageMaxHeight,$UploadDirectory .$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage))
    {
        //Create Thumbnail for the Image
        resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbMaxWidth,$ThumbMaxHeight,$UploadThumbDirectory.$NewThumbFileName,$CreatedImage);
        // Insert info into database table.. do w.e!
        $dbconn = mysql_connect($MySql_hostname, $MySql_username, $MySql_password)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        mysql_select_db($MySql_databasename,$dbconn);
        @mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (img_name, img_title, thumb_name, uploaded_date) VALUES ('$DestRandImageName', '$Imageitle','$NewThumbFileName','$uploaded_date')");
        mysql_close($dbconn);

        //respond with our images
        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td align="center"><img src="'.$UploadThumbDirectory.$NewThumbFileName.'" alt="Thumbnail"></td></tr><tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="'.$UploadDirectory .$DestRandImageName.'" alt="Resized Image"></td></tr></table>';

    }else{
        die('Upload Error'); //output error
    }
}

//function outputs upload error messages, http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#90522
function upload_errors($err_code) {
    switch ($err_code) { 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
            return 'No file was uploaded'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
            return 'Missing a temporary folder'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
            return 'Failed to write file to disk'; 
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
            return 'File upload stopped by extension'; 
        default: 
            return 'Unknown upload error'; 
    } 
} 


function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxWidth,$MaxHeight,$DestFolder,$SrcImage)
{
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxWidth/$CurWidth, $MaxHeight/$CurHeight);
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
    $NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);
    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        // copy file
        if(imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,100))
        {
            imagedestroy($NewCanves);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you will find your answer here see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation

Comment: GD will only handle the first frame of an animated gif. you're essentially destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

The GD image library and its associated functions can't handle animated gifs. If you can install the [Imagemagick library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php), you could manipulate animated gifs with those functions.