# Resizing animated .gifs with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, thumbnails, animated-gif

I know this has been asked in a few different ways before but I am running into what seems to be a unique problem. I am using the following code to resize animated .gif images:

```
convert $image -coalesce $image

convert -layers OptimizeTransparency -quality 60 -size 220x220 $image -resize 220 +profile '*' $thumb`
```

In theory this should generate a thumbnailed/resized version of the .gif at 220px X 220px and keep it at a reasonable size by reducing quality and optimizing transparency, but in production it takes a 255kb [.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZTD4.gif) and turns it into a 1.5mb thumbnail. What is wrong with this code and how can I create more optimized .gif thumbnails?

Comment: RTLM? http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#optframe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize animated gif file without destroying animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation)