# Resize animated gif in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upload, resize, thumbnails, animated-gif

Is there a way of resizing an animated gif image when uploading it in WordPress? I've seen a couple of threads that deal with ImageMagick in order to get this to work, but I'm merely interested in a WP solution that evolves around building a script based on WP's own resizing tools. Any direction on this subject is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not as easy to resize a gif using GD. You're better off using imagemagick. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/718500/551093

Comment: Yes, saw that thread. Think it's a bit to steep for me to build something outside of WP and sync.

Comment: The problem is that GD doesn't do what you want it to do. If there was an easier way, I would've linked you to it. I don't know what you mean about _"build outside of WP and sync"_, just create your own resize function for gifs and bind it to a hook (`image_downsize`, for example).

Comment: You're right, I could build functions inside WP. Will try that out, thanks.