# Animated GIF Image Resize with Imagick PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I wants to resize animated GIF images without loosing animation. Resize process is working fine but after resize animation goes away. Please check my script in-line if i am doing anything wrong

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-1
PECL Imagick Extension - 3.1.2

```
$images = $this->imageObj->coalesceImages();
foreach ($images as $frame) {
 $frame->thumbnailImage($this->thumbWidth, $this->thumbHeight);
 $frame->setImagePage($this->thumbWidth, $this->thumbHeight, 0, 0);
}

$this->imageObj = $images->deconstructImages();
$this->imageObj->writeImage($this->thumbImagePath);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize animated GIF file without destroying animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation)

Comment: also http://askubuntu.com/questions/257831/how-can-i-resize-an-animated-gif-file-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation). From the link:

> If you have imagemagick access, you can do this:
>
> ```
> system("convert big.gif -coalesce coalesce.gif");
> system("convert -size 200x100 coalesce.gif -resize 200x10 small.gif");
> ```

Comment: Hi I gone through all provided links before posting my question. I only wants to do it through PHP ImagicK pecl extension. I also tried writeImage with file_put_contents but it also does not helped.

Comment: @user524694, in the link i posted there is another way to do it.

Comment: Hi, I am able to resize animated GIF image now but when i stream same image with Imagick it renders image but animation lost and when i print same image with file_put_contents it renders image without loosing animation.

Comment: Hi may i know performance , resource utilization between streaming image using Imagick and readfile.

Comment: @user524694, I don't know.