# What is the most efficient method to make gifs from images using PHP?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gif

I'm writing a PHP script to take several images and compile them together into a GIF. Searching for resources on this subject, I have encountered several PHP specific ways to do this, such as ImageMagik or [GifCreator](https://github.com/Sybio/GifCreator) but the resources I encounter, including on here, [seem rather old.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation?rq=1) GifCreator hasn't been updated in 3 years, and I find that it fails to resize certain compressed gifs.

In the last several years, GIF and gif creation sites have exploded in popularity, and I can't imagine these methods from 2009 are still the most efficient way of going about this task.

What is the most efficient (stable, resource efficient) and modern way to create GIFs from a collection of images along with resizing GIFs with PHP? Are there better libraries available or is PHP not a good choice for this task?

Comment: sorry.   just realized you want to combine them.   for combining multiple images, personally, I would use ffmpeg.  There is a module available for php.  after making the mpeg/etc, then convert that into a gif, which you can also use ffmpeg to do (eg : http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html )

Comment: It is quite unclear to me what you want to achieve. Are you starting with JPEGs? Or animated GIFs? Or something else? You say you want to make GIFs from images - but GIFs are images. Maybe you can give an example?